# Receiving access token but not the refresh token from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: php, curl, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Graph API to fetch the calendar data from Outlook. For that I authenticate the user through the OAuth2.0 API. When the user grant the permission I get the access token without any problem. But unfortunately not the refresh token to refresh the access token.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$client_id = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
$client_secret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET";
$redirect = "MY_REDIRECT_URI";

if (!isset($_GET["code"])) {
    ?>
    <a class="btn btn-default-active" href="<?php
       echo "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
       . "client_id=$client_id"
       . "&"
       . "scope="
       . "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read"
       . "%20"
       . "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FCalendars.Read"
       . "%20"
       . "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FCalendars.Read.Shared"
       . "&response_type=code"
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect);
       ?>">Mit Office 365 verbinden</a><?php
} else {
    $code = $_GET["code"];

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Length"=>144
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "client_id" => $client_id,
            "client_secret" => $client_secret,
            "code" => $code,
            "redirect_uri" => $redirect),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
}
?>
```

I do it like the offical documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) from Microsoft, but still not get an refresh token, while in the documentation the response look like so:

```
{
  "access_token": " eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1THdqcHdBSk9NOW4tQSJ9.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.JZw8jC0gptZxVC-7l5sFkdnJgP3_tRjeQEPgUn28XctVe3QqmheLZw7QVZDPCyGycDWBaqy7FLpSekET_BftDkewRhyHk9FW_KeEz0ch2c3i08NGNDbr6XYGVayNuSesYk5Aw_p3ICRlUV1bqEwk-Jkzs9EEkQg4hbefqJS6yS1HoV_2EsEhpd_wCQpxK89WPs3hLYZETRJtG5kvCCEOvSHXmDE6eTHGTnEgsIk--UlPe275Dvou4gEAwLofhLDQbMSjnlV5VLsjimNBVcSRFShoxmQwBJR_b2011Y5IuD6St5zPnzruBbZYkGNurQK63TJPWmRd3mbJsGM0mf3CUQ",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "expires_on": "1388444763",
  "resource": "https://service.contoso.com/",
  "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4rTfgV29ghDOHRc2B-C_hHeJaJICqjZ3mY2b_YNqmf9SoAylD1PycGCB90xzZeEDg6oBzOIPfYsbDWNf621pKo2Q3GGTHYlmNfwoc-OlrxK69hkha2CF12azM_NYhgO668yfcUl4VBbiSHZyd1NVZG5QTIOcbObu3qnLutbpadZGAxqjIbMkQ2bQS09fTrjMBtDE3D6kSMIodpCecoANon9b0LATkpitimVCrl-NyfN3oyG4ZCWu18M9-vEou4Sq-1oMDzExgAf61noxzkNiaTecM-Ve5cq6wHqYQjfV9DOz4lbceuYCAA",
  "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read",
"id_token": " eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.”
}
```

In my case the respones looks like so:

```
{
"token_type":"Bearer",
"scope":"https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read.shared https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read",
"expires_in":3599,
"ext_expires_in":0,
"access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN"
}
```

What I also tried is to add the ressource tag, but still doesn't work. What is going wrong?

**UPDATE**

I now tried to adding the attribute:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "client_id" => $client_id,
        "client_secret" => $client_secret,
        "code" => $code,
        "redirect_uri" => $redirect,
        "prompt"=>"consent"),
```

It still doesn't work.

Comment: You probably need to request offline access to get a refresh token.

Comment: Okay and how do I do that?

Comment: try adding prompt=consent to your initial request for authentication.  Let me know if you get a refresh token then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question what I did. But I still doesn't give me a refresh token.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As DalmTo said, you need to request offline access to get a refresh token. You do this by adding `offline_access` to your `scope`.

In your case:

```
echo "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
   . "client_id=$client_id"
   . "&"
   . "scope="
   . "offline_access"
   . "%20"
   . "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read"
   . "%20"
   . "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FCalendars.Read"
   . "%20"
   . "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FCalendars.Read.Shared"
   . "&response_type=code"
   . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect);
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much. But you have to replace the dot in a underline character so from offline.access to offline_access.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that typo